# I scraped my car against my moms and i need to remove the white scratches

Tags: paint, suzuki, kia, paint-scratches

This morning, I scraped my car against my mom's car by accident. I noticed a white scuff above her rear driver tire as well on the front of my Suzuki xl7 with a dent. Can I get it out without taking it to the shop?

Comment: We need to be able to asses the damage in order to give a repair path.  Can you upload a few pictures of the dent as well as the scuff?

Comment: Welcome to the site! @DucatiKiller is right, we really need more to evaluate what you might have to do. Also, what is your skill level with metal work for working on the dent? The scratch might only take some buffing if it's not deep into the paint. The keys are pics, and how handy do you feel you are? As an example, me personally I'm a pretty handy guy, I can fix most things in the engine, but in depth body work and the automatic transmission are things I would never try to do.

Comment: Btw it's pretty likely that the question will get closed without additional information as it's just way to vague to be answerable. So please, help us to help you get what you need.

Comment: Can you show a picture please?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this method to pull certain types of dents.

Here is one method to resolve the dent issue.

## Dent Pulling

glue these plastic ding tabs to the center of the dent.  You can find them by googling "plastic ding tab"

You will use a [hot glue gun](https://www.google.com/search?q=hot%20glue%20gun&oq=hot%20glue%20gun&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2050j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) and hot glue them to your dent.
[image]

Use a dent puller slide hammer.  The tip should screw into the plastic ding pullers.

[image]

Pull the weight of the slide hammer to the bottom towards the dent and give it a good pull.  When the sliding weight hits the stop at the end of the hammer the transferred energy will pull onto the glued tab and pull the dent out.

You may need to repeat the operation a few times to get the way it needs to be.

## Scratches

You can use a [buffing pad](https://www.google.com/search?q=buffing%20wheel&oq=buffing%20wheel&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65j69i59j69i60l2.2004j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=paint%20buffing%20pad) to remove very light scratches by applying a very light grit rubbing compound and [using the buffer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_kCZmtZh88) to smooth them out.

The [rubbing compound](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubbing%20compound&oq=rubbing%20compound&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4689j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) should be available an auto paint store or simply an auto parts store.

Comment: What happens to the hot glue, then? Does it detach from the body in the process of pulling? And last - are the ding tabs reusable after the pull, or good for only one time each?

Comment: The hot glue just rolls off.  After it's cool you just start pushing on the edges toward the inside of the glue spot and it just peels off.  :-)